# Formatting template with custom form parameters

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a custom form with multiple fields I'd like to format in the template. Is there a way to align the outcomevalue fields to the right of the relevantoutcome choice options?

If there is no way then is there a way to name the outcomevalue_%s fields such that they link to a relevantoutcome option? For example if the relevantoutcome = Time, then the label for outcomevalue_%s = Time Value

forms.py

```
   self.fields['relevantoutcome']=forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Outcome.objects.all(),required=True, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
   self.fields['relevantoutcome'].label="Outcomes"

   outcome_qs=Outcome.objects.all()
   for outcome in outcome_qs:
       self.fields['outcomevalue_%s' % outcome.pk] = forms.CharField(required=False)
       self.fields['outcomevalue_%s' % outcome.pk].label = "Outcome Value"
```

template.html

```
   {{form.as_table}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to go is probably writing your own templatetag for your forms.

template.html

```
{% load yourapp_tags %}

{{ form|as_table }}
```

yourapp_tags.py

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def as_table(value):
    #do the formatting
    return value
```

For docs on how to use your own templatetags, take a look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/custom-template-tags/).